# Function works in query but not in constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem: I have a database of a Hotel, and I have to handle collisions while booking rooms.

So let's say, Quest1 wants to book room2 between 2016-11-10 and 2016-11-15, but this room has been booked by Quest3 between 2016-11-07 and 2016-11-14 (You can book the room FROM the day people leave), and my function should be called in a constraint to tell he cant book it for those dates.

I have an EMPTY table for bookings. The problem is, that when using the function in a query, it returns that room2 was booked 0 times between 2016-11-10 and 2016-11-15 (since the table is empty. even if its not empty, it will return the right value too, tested it.), but while using it as a constraint, it comes up as the row was not updated, the insert statement is conflicted with my constraint.

The function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Booked]
(
   @room int,
   @from date,
   @to date
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

return(
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM BOOKINGS
   WHERE room = @room AND NOT (@from >= to OR @to < from)
)

END
```

Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE BOOKINGS ADD 
CONSTRAINT chk_isBooked 
CHECK ([dbo].Booked([room], [from],[to])=(0))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify the complete constraint definition please?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, i totally forgot to add that one.

    ALTER TABLE BOOKINGS
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_isBooked CHECK ([dbo].[Booked]([room],
    [(from],[to])=(0))

Comment: I dont really think it is, the poster wants to know how to create a function and a check, my problem is, even though i created a working functions which return the right value, the constraint seems to be off-track. 
Sorry if i failed to be specific enough

Comment: No worries, I thought the duplicate link contained a working example. I'll remove the close-vote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the tip, im looking into it and report back if i find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script does work. It appears that when the CHECK constraint is fired, the row is already in the table and is being counted in the function. I added an indentity to the bookings table to avoid that.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.bookings(
    id int identity(1,1),
    room int ,
    [from] date,
    [to] date
);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsBooked(@id int,@room int, @from date, @to date)
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE id<>@id AND room=@room AND NOT(@from>=[to] OR @to<[from])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.bookings ADD CONSTRAINT chk_isbooked CHECK (dbo.IsBooked(id,room,[from],[to])=0);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.bookings(room,[from],[to])VALUES(1,'20160101','20160107'); -- success
INSERT INTO dbo.bookings(room,[from],[to])VALUES(1,'20160101','20160107'); -- fail
```

Comment: Now I feel like I'm retarded. Many thanks for the explanation, my problem has been solved. And thanks for @GordonLidoff too, for putting me on a path, i learned a lot while searching through Stackoverflow with the keyword 'udf' and 'constraint'. Thank you guys once more!